# Mutli indexing using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

df

```
ITEM      CATEGORY       COLOR

48684      CAR           RED
54519      BIKE          BLACK
14582      CAR           BLACK
45685      JEEP          WHITE
23661      BIKE          BLUE
```

I tried using the below code

```
df.groupby(['CATEGORY', 'COLOR']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

which does not give me what I need. The output I am expecting is

```
CATEGORY      COLOR     ITEM

CAR           RED       48684
              BLACK     14582
BIKE          BLACK     54519
              BLUE      23661 
JEEP          WHITE     45685
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['CATEGORY', 'COLOR']).sort_index()
print (df1)
                 ITEM
CATEGORY COLOR       
BIKE     BLACK  54519
         BLUE   23661
CAR      BLACK  14582
         RED    48684
JEEP     WHITE  45685
```

If order is omportant convert both columns to [ordered categoricals](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#series-creation):

```
cols = ['CATEGORY', 'COLOR']
for c in cols:
    df[c] = pd.Categorical(df[c], categories=df[c].drop_duplicates(), ordered=True)

df1 = df.set_index(cols).sort_index()
print (df1)
                 ITEM
CATEGORY COLOR       
CAR      RED    48684
         BLACK  14582
BIKE     BLACK  54519
         BLUE   23661
JEEP     WHITE  45685
```

Answer (score 0):

I will use `Categorical` first, since this will keep the original `CATEGORY` order

```
df.CATEGORY=pd.Categorical(df.CATEGORY,df.CATEGORY.unique())
s=df.sort_values(['CATEGORY','COLOR']).set_index(['CATEGORY','COLOR'])
                 ITEM
CATEGORY COLOR       
CAR      BLACK  14582
         RED    48684
BIKE     BLACK  54519
         BLUE   23661
JEEP     WHITE  45685
```